# Discord method not functioning

Tags: javascript, discord

Hi I’m looking to see why this doesn't work I'm not familiar with js so if anyone could help me that'll be appreciated. This worked like a month ago and now it doesn't

```
function FindModule(item) {
  var req = window.webpackJsonp.push([
    [],
    { __extra_id__: (module, exports, req) => (module.exports = req) },
    [["__extra_id__"]]
  ]);

  for (const in1 in req.c) {
    if (req.c.hasOwnProperty(in1)) {
      const m = req.c[in1].exports;
      if (m && m.__esModule && m.default && m.default[item]) return m.default;
      if (m && m[item]) return m;
    }
  }
}

let amount = 60;
let guildid = "GUILDIDHERE";
let channelid = "CHANNELIDHERE";
let interval = 1000;
let message = "message ";
var memberList = FindModule("getMembers").getMembers(guildid);

setInterval(function () {
  let users = "";
  for (var index = memberList.length - 1; index > 0; index--) {
    var rndIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
    var temp = memberList[rndIndex];
    memberList[rndIndex] = memberList[index];
    memberList[index] = temp;
  }

  memberList.slice(0, amount).forEach((member) => {
    users += `<@${member.userId}>`;
  });
  FindModule("sendMessage").sendMessage(channelid, {
    content: `${users} ${message}`
  });
}, interval);
```

when I run this it says:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
```

Comment: It means window.webpackJsonp is undefined so not related to Discord.